# Linux, search for extended attribute value

Tags: linux, filesystems, directory, files, attributes

When a directory contains some files with non-empty extended attributes, all the attribute values can be shown as follows:

```
$ getfattr -d *
# file: file1
user.comment="comment1"

# file: file2
user.comment="comment2"
```

This should work for all the Linux distributions.

Is it possible to list only the files whose `user.comment` extended attribute has a specific value, for example `comment1`? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Try issuing `getfattr -n user.comment --only-values * | grep -B 1 "comment1"`

This will display the `user.comment` values of all files and filter the output with `grep`. You can of course use more sophisticated approaches, for example with `find -exec`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to dump the extended attributes to a file and then use awk

```
getfattr --dump * > xfatrrts.txt
```

or with a bash function

```
 ea_query() {
    a=$1; v=$2
    shift 3
    getfattr -n $a $* |
    awk "BEGIN  {
      RS="# file: "
      FS="n"
   }/="$v"/ { print $1 }"
}
```

and then

```
cp `ea_query user.important yes *.txt` important_texts/
```

In zsh

```
fattr() {
  local val=$(getfattr -e text -n user.$1 --only-values $REPLY 2>/dev/null)
  [[ -n $val && ( -z $2 || $val = $2 ) ]]
}
```

And then

```
ls *(e:fattr year 2020:)
```

Here you will find a few other  solutions https://linux-user.gr/t/ektetamenes-idiothtes-archeiwn/2379 (in greek).